# I can't get the if statements to appear when I run the function

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement

I know it's basic but I'm trying to show the if statements depending on the input I put in the function but they do not show up. Only the result of the calculation of the variable shows up. If not I run the function it will only give me a number as a result. (It's in kg and meters)

```
function bmiCalculator (weight, height) {
    var bmi = weight / Math.pow(height,2)
    return bmi = Math.round(bmi * 10) / 10;

 if (bmi <= 18.5) {
    ("Your BMI is " + bmi + ", so you are underweight.");
}

if (bmi > 18.5 && bmi === 24.9) {
    ("Your BMI is " + bmi + ", so you have a normal weight.");
}

if (bmi > 24.9) {
    ("Your BMI is " + bmi + ", so you are overweight.");
}

}
```

I was expecting to get the if statements depending on your BMI. I tried changing the if statements to different places to see if it worked but nothing.

Comment: The `if` statements are unreachable because of the `return` on the second line of the function! May be the return should be `var` or `let` or even `const`

Comment: your process ends as soon as you return something you know? everything after it, will not be read. So after this line `return bmi = Math.round(bmi * 10) / 10;` you will return only the value of `bmi` and nothing else

Comment: Side note: `if (bmi > 18.5 && bmi === 24.9) {` You probably want `<=` and not `===` there.

Comment: also, even if you could reach the `if`s, just putting a string expression in there doesn't have any observable effect. You need to *do something* with that string, which could be outputting it somewhere (the browser console, or the page) or simply returning it so it can be used by something else.

Answer (score 2):

When you return the result of a function, the process ends there which means it won't read the rest of the code(any of the if statements written there won't be read).

This is what you should do instead:

1- use `let` to declare variables that will change during the process

2- declare a single variable that will be your result that you will return form your function and after your conditions you can return it just once.

3- fix your conditions a bit, this line here is not doing what you expect it to do: `if (bmi > 18.5 && bmi === 24.9) {`

4- finally return your result just once at the end of the function

```js
function bmiCalculator(weight, height) {
  let result = "";
  let bmi = weight / Math.pow(height, 2)
  bmi = Math.round(bmi * 10) / 10;

  if (bmi <= 18.5) {
    result = "Your BMI is " + bmi + ", so you are underweight.";
  } else if (bmi > 18.5 && bmi <= 24.9) {
    result = "Your BMI is " + bmi + ", so you have a normal weight.";
  } else {
    result = "Your BMI is " + bmi + ", so you are overweight.";
  }
  return result;

}

console.log(bmiCalculator(55, 1.75))
console.log(bmiCalculator(65, 1.75))
console.log(bmiCalculator(92, 1.75))
```

Comment: Or as a one-liner, ``const bmiCalculator = (weight, height, bmi = Math.round (weight / Math.pow(height, 2) * 10) / 10) => `Your BMI is ${bmi} so you ${bmi <= 18.5 ? 'are underweight.' : bmi <= 24.9 ?  'you have a normal weight.' : 'you are overweight.}` ``

Comment: yes, there is always a more elegant way for doing things

Comment: Thank you so much Chris!! I still have a lot to learn and this really taught me since I am very new as you can see by my code haha. Really, thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Observe the code. You put the return statement before the if statements,
so your program will never reach them, and will return only what it says it will return, e.g. the BMI.
Furthermore, it seems that you want to return the String corresponding the conditions, so you should write if... return "Your BMI is..." etc.

Comment: If anyone thinks there is something wrong with my answer, tell me!

Comment: probably becuz what you answered was already pointed out in the comments. Repeating what was already mentioned is just redundancy. On top of that the early return statement was not the only problem with his code

Comment: @Chris-G That's unfair to judge by comments! Firstly, the comments were posted simultaneously to my answer, Secondly comments are by definition comments and not answers. Furthermore, I was not doing a full code review, I answered his specific question to which the solution was the correction of the position of the return statement.

Comment: I didn't judge I'm just saying the usual reasons for down-vote in here based on experience. Also the point of giving an answer is to mention everything that is wrong with the code. That is what gives more value to an answer. Ppl are free to down-vote your answer if they don't think it's valuable enough. If you react to a down-vote, that will just attract more down-votes. Answers are more valuable if you point out more mistakes, bad practices, etc. Rather than just ignoring those

Comment: @Chris-G Fair enough, but in that case (re: full answer) he should be asking on the code-review SE. But I guess it is rather conflated at times.

Comment: If he ask for a code review, this is not the place for it, his question will be downvoted to oblivion and will be closed for not asking a specific question.  I think there is another page where you can ask those kind of questions